# Adding a bootstrap class to rails form time_select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap has the class 'form-control' to add to select boxes to give them styling. I was able to do it successfully so for the following field:

```
 <%= f.collection_select :team_a_id, @teams, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select first team"}, {class: "form-control"} %>
```

However I have the following form field for time_select. I need to apply an html class(preferably "form-control") to the following form field and have not been successful in doing so with the same approach above.

```
 <%= f.time_select :match_time, prompt: {hour: 'Choose hour', minute: 'Choose minute'}, minute_step: 15 %>
```

How would I approach this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The html_options is the third parameter, as described in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-time_select):

```
time_select(method, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

so something like this should work:

```
 <%= f.time_select :method, { prompt: {hour: 'Choose hour', minute: 'Choose minute'}, minute_step: 15 }, { class: 'form-control' } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

From [DOCs](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_select)

`time_select(object_name, method, options = {}, html_options = {})`

Probably you are looking smth like this:

`<%= f.time_select :match_time, '', {prompt: {hour: 'Choose hour', minute: 'Choose minute'}, minute_step: 15}, class: "form-control" %>`