# <select> created by time_select is missing class="form-control"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, phoenix-framework

Styling `<select>` in Bootstrap 3.3.7 can be done like so:

```html
<select class="form-control">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
```

The key is the class `form-control`. When I use `time_select` from `Phoenix.HTML.Form` in my `html.eex` that creates a `<select>`, **the class is not added** even when I specify it:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :break, "Pause", class: "control-label" %>
    <%= time_select f, :break, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

The resulting HTML looks like this:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="training_break">Pause</label>
    <select id="training_break_hour" name="training[break][hour]">
        <option value="0">00</option>
        ...
```

*How do I add the class `form-control` to the `<select>` here?*

---

I've noticed that other types of inputs do add the class, e.g. `text_input`:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <%= label f, :title, "Titel", class: "control-label" %>
    <%= text_input f, :title, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

This results in that:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="training_title">Titel</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="training_title" name="training[title]" type="text">
</div>
```

Another thing I've found is this post: [Adding a bootstrap class to rails form time_select field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37353083/12323248). It states the same problem, sadly there is no such HTML-specific parameter for [Phoenix' version](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#time_select/3) of that function.

Maybe I'm just missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a function that generates just one `<select>` (e.g. `select`), you can add the class like so:

```html
<%= select f, :age, class: "form-control" %>
```

When you use a function that generates *more than one* `<select>`s (e.g. `date_select`), to add the class you need to address each one separately like so:

```html
<%= date_select f, :date,
    [
        year: [class: "form-control"],
        month: [class: "form-control"],
        day: [class: "form-control"]
    ] %>
```

This will add the class `form-control` to all three generated `<select>`s.